# Neon pothos turning green. Why?

Tags: houseplants

My neon pothos leaves recently started showing green color from the edges. Why is this happening? Cut marks also keep appearing on the leaves 
out of nowhere. Is it due to some fungus or pest?
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does it receive direct sunlight?

Comment: Yes, it does. It receives direct sunlight for 3-4 hours and then indirect for rest of the day.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect its not appreciating the direct sunlight it is receiving - these plants prefer indirect, bright light, so try moving it to somewhere it doesn't get any sunlight at all, but does receive good daylight, somewhere like a northfacing window (if you are in the northern hemisphere). General care instructions here https://www.thespruce.com/pothos-an-easy-to-grow-houseplant-1403154